# ruby mongoDB insert_many - success message but no inserts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb

I'm trying to do insert_many using [Ruby Driver of MongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/ruby-driver/current/tutorials/ruby-driver-bulk-operations/) but it's not working. Any help would be appreciated.

Here's my sample model:

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :message
end
```

MongoDB Rails code:

```
client = Mongo::Client.new('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/development')
collection = client[:user]
u = Hash.new
u['message'] = 'hi'
documents = []
documents << u
result = collection.insert_many(documents)

#<Mongo::BulkWrite::Result:0x00007fa6ed4e99b8 @results={"n_inserted"=>1, "n"=>1, "inserted_ids"=>[BSON::ObjectId('5e9ac4c6c40dc6a955465a8f')]}>
```

When I verify the insert, it seems to work, but when I query the model, there's no data:

```
result
#<Mongo::BulkWrite::Result:0x00007fa6ed4e99b8 @results={"n_inserted"=>1, "n"=>1, "inserted_ids"=>[BSON::ObjectId('5e9ac4c6c40dc6a955465a8f')]}>

User.count
0
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Just a tip: use literals `u = { 'message' => 'hi' }` and `documents = [u]` instead of whatever that is.

Comment: You are not using this correctly. Check the documentation: https://docs.mongodb.com/mongoid/current/tutorials/getting-started-rails

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out the issue. It's the collection itself. All I need to do is this to get the collection, then I can apply MongDB Ruby Driver methods:

```
user_collection = User.collection
```